# MAUI: Can I skip building for Android or iOS when I'm building either platform?

Tags: msbuild, maui, .net-8.0

Basically the title says all.
MAUI has a single project format for iOS and Android. When I'm debugging on iOS, I don't want MSBuild to build Android as well and vice-versa, because it gets slow.
Other than creating two projects, are there no other options?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to achieve this is to add new build configurations to your solution, one for Android and one for iOS (and if you wish also the remaining platforms) and then updating the `TargetFrameworks` with a build condition.

## Step 1: Add new build configurations

First, locate the configuration manager, by clicking the little triangle next to "Debug":

[image: Configuration Dropdown]

Then select "Configuration Manager" to see this dialog:

[image: Configuration Manager]

Here, you can now open the "Active solution configuration" dropdown and select "New". In the next dialog, you can then create your Android-specific configuration:

[image: Android-only configuration]

Repeat the same step for iOS:

[image: iOS-only configuration]

Then, in case you are using a Unit Test project, you need to disable building the test project with these configurations:

[image: Test project configuration]

## Step 2: Add build conditions for TargetFrameworks

Now, you can edit the *.csproj* file of your MAUI project and add the conditions to the property group at the top:

```xml
<TargetFrameworks Condition="'$(Configuration)'=='Debug Android'">net8.0-android</TargetFrameworks>
<TargetFrameworks Condition="'$(Configuration)'=='Debug iOS'">net8.0-ios</TargetFrameworks>
<TargetFrameworks Condition="'$(Configuration)'=='Debug' OR '$(Configuration)'=='Release'">net8.0;net8.0-android;net8.0-ios;net8.0-maccatalyst</TargetFrameworks>
<TargetFrameworks Condition="('$(Configuration)'=='Debug' OR '$(Configuration)'=='Release') AND $([MSBuild]::IsOSPlatform('windows'))">$(TargetFrameworks);net8.0-windows10.0.19041.0</TargetFrameworks>
```

## Step 3: Update Test project *(if you have one)*

Finally, you'll need to update the *.csproj* file of your test project and add conditions to the item groups so that it only builds with the supported configurations (here: *Debug* and *Release*):

```xml
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net8.0</TargetFramework>
    <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
    <Nullable>enable</Nullable>

    <IsPackable>false</IsPackable>

    <Configurations>Debug;Release;Debug Android;Debug iOS;</Configurations>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)'=='Debug' OR '$(Configuration)'=='Release'">
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Maui.Dependencies" Version="6.0.547" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.NET.Test.Sdk" Version="17.3.2" />
    <PackageReference Include="NUnit" Version="3.13.3" />
    <PackageReference Include="NUnit3TestAdapter" Version="4.2.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="NUnit.Analyzers" Version="3.3.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="coverlet.collector" Version="3.1.2" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)'=='Debug' OR '$(Configuration)'=='Release'">
    <ProjectReference Include="..\MauiSamples\MauiSamples.csproj" />
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

## Final Notes

This approach generally works, I've tried it out. However, switching between configurations sometimes leads to project load failures or failures to establish the Mac build host connection or other issues. If you don't switch between platforms very often, this approach might be suitable, otherwise, you'll have to live with how it is or manually comment/uncomment the target platform identifiers as proposed in an another answer.

If you want to see a working example, I've created a separate branch where I've tried this in my [MAUI Samples repo](https://github.com/ewerspej/maui-samples/blob/platform_specific_build_configurations/MauiSamples/MauiSamples/MauiSamples.csproj).

Comment: Yeah, I was thinking of avoiding this. My shared library feeds 8 apps, thats 16 configuration(s) and the apps are gonna increase with time. But if nothing else works, probably this is the way to go.

Comment: @zyzzyxx I believe this is the only way to go unless you want to change the target platform identifiers manually all the time.

Comment: Yep. It seems so. I tried using Directory.build.props, but that didn't work either. Thanks anyways.

Answer (score 1):

## This is a a hacky way to do it!!!

The only way I can think of off the top of my head, is go to this line in the project file

```
<TargetFrameworks>net8.0-android;net8.0-ios;net8.0-maccatalyst</TargetFrameworks>
```

And remove the project you don't want to build so if I only want iOS

```
<TargetFrameworks>net8.0-ios</TargetFrameworks>
```

And then restore nugets

But make sure you don't commit this, you don't want your messing around to reach the server :P

Answer (score 1):

You can add conditions to your targeted frameworks based on the platform that's building the project.

[Here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/property-functions?view=vs-2022#msbuild-property-functions)'s the documentation for MSBuild property functions.

```
<TargetFrameworks Condition="$([MSBuild]::IsOSPlatform('windows'))=='false'"> $(TargetFrameworks);net8.0-ios</TargetFrameworks>
```

When it comes to the operating systems that the project is built on, you can use the [OSPlatform struct](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.interopservices.osplatform?view=net-8.0).

Comment: Actually, the `IsOSPlatform('windows')` condition relates to the OS on which the IDE and compiler are running, it's not related to the target platform.

Comment: Well yeah. We use this for building the app for iOS only on mac/linux as there isn't an iOS emulator for windows(at least for visual studio).  This would be a solution for VS for windows. When it comes to macOS it's a different story as it can run both.

Comment: Well, I think it's not what the OP wants or needs. It's specifically about the target platforms.